# Enviar mensajes desde Servlet a Java Script

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, richfaces

Tengo una duda que me ha quitado un poco de tiempo.

Estoy trabajando con un *Handsondtable*, componente de tabla JS. Resulta que cuando me insertan datos en la tabla, los mando al Servlet por medio de un llamado desde el JavaScript. En el servlet realizo todas las validaciones necesarias pero tengo problemas a la hora de recibir mensajes en el JSP, ya que el llamado lo hice desde el JavaScript y no se como entablar comunicación con el Servlet desde JS.

A continuación el código del llamado

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "req.jsonServlet", //LLAMO AL SERVLET
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',  //POR EL METODO POST
    data: {action: "import_items_products_IPD", //EL NOMBRE DE LA ACCION EN EL SERVLET
       datos: quitar(algo),                                                                             
       manufacturer: manufacturerId, 
       contactManufacturer : contactManufacturerId,
       productLine: productLineId,
       harmonizedC: harmonizedCode,
       client: clientId,
       contactClient: contactClientId,
       supplier : supplierId,
       contactSupplier: contactSupplierId},
             success: function () {
                 alert('Products import successfully.');
             },
             error : function(obj,req){
                 alert('Error trying to import the products.');
             }
});
```

Como pueden ver en el anterior código, ahí es donde hago el llamado al Servlet desde el java Script, pero luego de hacer el procedimiento en la Servlet, no se como retornar el mensaje y mostrarlo ya sea con un Alert o lo que sea.

El código del Servlet es este, y desde ahí necesito enviar los mensajes.

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher vista = request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8080/SOFTLOT/faces/jsp/reports/IPDepartment/importQuoteRequest.jsp");
    try {

        if("import_items_products_IPD".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("action"))){
            int manufacturerId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("manufacturer"));
            int contactManufacturerId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contactManufacturer"));
            int productLineId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productLine"));
            String harmonizedCode = request.getParameter("harmonizedC");
            int clientId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("client"));
            int contactClientId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contactClient"));
            int supplierId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("supplier"));
            int contactSupplierId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contactSupplier"));

            String losParametros = request.getParameter("datos");

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ProductImport [] listadeProductos = mapper.readValue(losParametros, ProductImport[].class);
            List<ProductImport> productsList = Arrays.asList(listadeProductos);


            boolean saved = saveImportedProducts(manufacturerId, contactManufacturerId,productLineId, harmonizedCode, clientId, contactClientId,
                     supplierId, contactSupplierId, productsList);

            if(!saved){
                vista.forward(request, response);
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Simplemente lo que necesito es validar un dato de la tabla anteriormente mencionada y retornar un mensaje desde el Servlet a el JavaScript y mostrarlo en el JSP.

Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda, comunidad.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código de tu Servlet a la pregunta, puedes [edit] y añadirlo

Comment: Hola puedes revisar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax